# Как вызвать новое окно?

Tags: java, javafx, intellij-idea

По нажатию кнопки должна появляться новое окно, и закрываться старое.
Я использую контроллеры для каждого FXML. Обоработчик нажатия на кнопку также в контролле, а создание окна в main.
Желательно с помощью `FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("file.fxml"))`

Answer (score 0):

Если окно должно быть основным, а не модульным, то контроллеру кнопки надо иметь объект сцены.

Имея объект сцены вы сможете убрать оттуда текущую и положить нужную вам, действия теже самые, что при инициализации первого окна.

Comment: Скорее модальное окно, а не модульное.

Comment: Как объект сцены достать и передать из объекта Main(в этом классе стартует приложение) в контроллер?

Comment: @SergG да, я так передавал, но возможно есть решение по лучше. При создании окна получите его контроллер и в нем вызовите метод setStage предварительно его написав конечно.